# Pennsylvania Taxation of Treasury Bonds Purchased on the Secondary Market

Tags: united-states, bonds, interest, state-income-tax, pennsylvania

How does Pennsylvania tax the following items for TREASURIES (purchased on the secondary market):

- Accrued Market Discount (1099-B Box 1f)
- Bond Premium on US Treasuries (1099-INT Line 12)
- Accrued Interest Paid on Purchases (1099B)

**Example**:

- Treasury Interest: $1000
- Accrued Market discount: $300
- Bond Premium: $100
- Accrued Interest Paid: $200

Federal Taxable Interest = 1000 + 300 - 100 - 200 = $1000

PA State Taxable Interest = ????

Thank you.